# Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE)

Tags: mysql

I have actually changed the collations of my tables to `utf8_general_ci` in mysql but it appears that it is still recognized as latin1 because I got this

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=': SELECT  `dimensions`.* FROM `dimensions` WHERE `dimensions`.`name` = '责任心' AND `dimensions`.`category` = '态度项' LIMIT 1

I don't write mysql query but I call someones code to generate one and execute it. And I used this statement to change the collation:

```
ALTER table participants CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And I also found out that I used the wrong collation instead of the correct one `utf8mb4_general_ci`. So I try to alter it by using.

```
ALTER table participants CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

But I got this error

> Error Code: 1253. COLLATION 'utf8mb4_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8

How can I fix it?

---Update---

Now all my tables are using `utf8mb4_general_ci` but I still get the same error `Illegal mix of collations`.

I used `show table status` to see the collations of my table.

Comment: Is it done for table and column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat' while using union all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568094/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-concat-while-using-union-all)

Comment: @Ingus I don't think so because I am not using concat.

Comment: ignore concat focus on the problem. ..

Comment: I bet you have different collation for table and columns

Comment: @Ingus I don't think that would help because I don't write mysql query but call someones code to generate one and execute it.

Comment: just check and fix it if i m correct!

Comment: You ahve alos to check if aby columns have teh "wrong swdish characterset) so do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805964/5193536 and change also the column

Comment: @Ingus My replies are based the fact that I have read the post. And I am curious about how I could know the collation of columns.

Comment: @Seaky if you use phpMyAdmin you can see it when click on table structure

Comment: @Ingus Thanks! They do have different collations. Do I need to change the column collation one by one manually or there is a query that could fix all?

Comment: I have no current code for that (i use HeidiSQL and it allow to check to convert all at once) So if you have no known code for that it need to be done one by one.

Comment: SET NAMES utf8; sometimes seems to solve a bunch of problems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the proper character set `utf8mb4` which should contain the given collation?

Comment: Thank you! This is the fix for my second problem. What about the first one?

Comment: CHECK THE COLUMNS

Comment: Yeah, what about the first one? Can you share all data for that to make the problem reproducable for others? What are the collations for `category` and `name`? Which character set have you used for the database connection? Have you tried skipping one of the `WHERE` clauses to see which one triggers the error?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't skip the `where` because I don't write sql queries but call well-incapsulated code to generate them.

Comment: Then why not copy the **exact same** query to some tool like phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, or the MySQL shell to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I mean I know the problem but I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci